# I am having some wrong concept about wildcard in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am trying to understand how to use wildcard in Java.

```
import java.util.List;
public class WildcardError{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}

public class WildcardFixed{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        fooHelper(i);
    }
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l){
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

- Why the first class cannot be compiled whereas the second one can?
- What happen when compiler sees the wildcard? turns it into Object? like `void foo(Object i)` in the first class, or `void foo(List<Object> i)`.
- How type inference works in the second class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wildcard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WildcardFixed wf = new WildcardFixed();
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
    li.add(0);
    wf.foo(li);
    System.out.println("Success");
    }
}

class WildcardError{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}

class WildcardFixed{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        fooHelper(i);
    }
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l){
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

The `WildcardError` class fails to compile with message

> The method set(int, capture#1-of ?) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#2-of ?)

In plainer English, the compiler is saying that it doesn't know what type of thing is contained in `i`, i.e. it doesn't know what type is returned by the `get()`, and it doesn't know what type of argument the `set()` takes, so it can't guarantee that the `set()` operation will succeed.

`WildcardFixed`, however, compiles simply because we reassure the compiler that, whatever type is in `l`, the result of the `get` will be the same type, `T`, as the argument type of the `set`. The compiler doesn't need much to go on, but it needs more than `?`.

You can get simpler, though. If you put the type parameter `T` into the original `foo()` method, everything compiles and runs perfectly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wildcard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WildcardFixed wf = new WildcardFixed();
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
    li.add(0);
    wf.foo(li);
    System.out.println("Success WildcardFixed");

    WildcardWithT wt = new WildcardWithT();
    wt.foo(li);
    System.out.println("Success WildcardWithT");
    }
}

class WildcardError{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}

class WildcardFixed{
    void foo(List<?> i){
        fooHelper(i);
    }
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l){
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}

class WildcardWithT {
    <T> void foo(List<T> i) {
    i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you could have passed a `List<String>`, so if you set an element with an Object (the result of `l.get(0)`), you cannot actually do that type-safely. *A bit of a myopic view.*

In the second example, `l.get(0)` is a T, and fits perfectly in the `l.set`,

Answer (score 2):

Good tutorial explaining this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

> ...
>
> It isn't safe to add arbitrary objects to it however:

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
```

> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?, it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.
>
> On the other hand, given a List, we can call get() and make use of the result. The result type is an unknown type, but we always know that it is an object. It is therefore safe to assign the result of get() to a variable of type Object or pass it as a parameter where the type Object is expected.